# Laravel Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to store data from a form into two tables on database when the radio button value on my view is "new", but the below problem was happened. But if the value is "existing", it's works fine.
what wrong with my code ?

> Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `customers` (`company_name`, `address`, `service_id`, `tc_name`, `tc_dept`, `tc_phone`, `tc_email`, `bill_name`, `bill_dept`, `bill_phone`, `bill_email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (PT Bank ABC, JL Sudirman, 1, Budi, Technical, 0812345678, budi@abc.co.id, Joko, Finance, 08123456789, joko@abc.co.id, 2016-12-14 11:21:26, 2016-12-14 11:21:26))

here my store code

```
if($request->select_data == 'new'){
        $customer = New Customer;
        $customer->company_name = $request->company_name;
        $customer->address = $request->address;
        $customer->service_id = $request->service_id;
        $customer->tc_name = $request->tc_name;
        $customer->tc_dept = $request->tc_dept;
        $customer->tc_phone = $request->tc_phone;
        $customer->tc_email = $request->tc_email;
        $customer->bill_name = $request->bill_name;
        $customer->bill_dept = $request->bill_dept;
        $customer->bill_phone = $request->bill_phone;
        $customer->bill_email = $request->bill_email;
        $customer->save();

        $salesorder = New SalesOrder;
        $salesorder->pid = $request->pid;
        $salesorder->project_name = $request->project_name;
        $salesorder->customer_id = $request->company_id;
        $salesorder->total = $request->totalfee;
        $salesorder->status = 'submit';
        $salesorder->detail = $request->detail;
        $salesorder->save();
    }else{
        $salesorder = New SalesOrder;
        $salesorder->pid = $request->pid;
        $salesorder->project_name = $request->project_name;
        $salesorder->customer_id = $request->company_id;
        $salesorder->total = $request->totalfee;
        $salesorder->status = 'submit';
        $salesorder->detail = $request->detail;
        $salesorder->save();
        //dd($salesorder);
    }
```

`dd($request->all());` result

```
array:32 [▼
  "sales_order_id" => "9"
  "select_data" => "new"
  "company_id" => "2"
  "company_name" => "PT Bank ABC"
  "address" => "JL Sudirman"
  "tc_name" => "Budi"
  "tc_dept" => "Technical"
  "tc_phone" => "0812345678"
  "tc_email" => "budi@abc.co.id"
  "bill_name" => "Joko"
  "bill_dept" => "Finance"
  "bill_phone" => "08123456789"
  "bill_email" => "joko@abc.co.id"
  "pid" => "PID002"
  "project_name" => "Implementasi"
  "order_identifier" => array:2 [▶]
  "service_name" => array:2 [▶]
  "service_id" => array:2 [▶]
  "order_type" => array:2 [▶]
  "select_plan" => array:2 [▶]
  "qty" => array:2 [▶]
  "unit_price" => array:2 [▶]
  "total_price" => array:2 [▶]
  "note" => array:2 [▶]
  "emp_name" => array:1 [▶]
  "emp_id" => array:1 [▶]
  "position" => array:1 [▶]
  "position_id" => array:1 [▶]
  "mandays" => array:1 [▶]
  "detail" => "Coba Coba"
  "totalfee" => "3100"    
  "_token" => "uxmXBwJKHWIoXDSFetU4oRgTiTftYEhhdpx4CaPr"
]
```

radio button html code

```
<div class="row-fluid select_data">
                        <input name="select_data" id="select_data" type="radio" value="new">
                        <span class="lbl">New</span>
                        <input name="select_data" id="select_data" type="radio" value="existing">
                        <span class="lbl">Existing</span>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Please post result of `dd($request->all())`

Comment: can you please share the radio button added html code

Comment: hi, i've been updated my question code

Comment: keep $input=Input::all(); print_r($input); check which value you are getting to controller

Comment: Your problem is the service_id is an array. Please open this array and check the contents   `"service_id" => array:2 [▶]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because some of `$request` properties are arrays. You can't store an array in `integer`, `string` etc columns. If you want to store them as arrays, you can serialize them:

```
$customer->service_id = json_encode(service_id);
```

And store in `text` or `json` columns:

```
$table->json('service_id');
$table->text('service_id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change id of both the radio buttons, you can not set same id for different elements, it will behave differently

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this one

<input name="select_data" name="select_data" type="radio" value="new">
                        <span class="lbl">New</span>
                        <input name="select_data" name="select_data" type="radio" value="existing">
                        <span class="lbl">Existing</span>
```